# DataGridCheckBoxColumn - How to return checked rows?

Tags: c#, database, wpf

In WPF I have a datagrid which I populate with data from a datatable (as a return of sql data) plus, I inserted a CheckBoxColumn. Displaying the data works. Now I want to print all values of column "Application" to console where a checkbox of CheckBoxolumn is checked. How does this work?

WPF code snippet:

```
     <DataGrid Name="AvailableApps" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,30,5,5" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Application" Binding="{Binding Application}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selection"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

C# code snippet:

```
        AvailableApps.ItemsSource = AppsAvailable.AsDataView();
        AvailableApps.IsReadOnly = false;
        AvailableApps.Columns[1].IsReadOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Didn't run the code yet, but I'd do something like (use LINQ):</s>
I've partly replicated the OP's code, since I don't have the structure of `AppsAvailable`, I've created a simple `ObservableCollection` of `Tuple<string, bool>` and used it as the items source.

```
    AvailableApps.Items.OfType<Tuple<string, bool>>()
        .Where(i => i.Item2 == true)
        .Select(i => i.Item1)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine($"{i}"));
```

What it does:

- it takes all the items of the `DataGrid` and casts them to the suitable type (in the OP's case it should be `OfType<typeOf(AppsAvailable)>` or better the actual type)
- filters the tuples for only those where checkbox was checked (explicit condition, more readability) - in case of the OP they should check for the condition they populate the checkbox column
- extracts the string values - in case of the OP they should use the component with the requested content
- prints one by one in the console (already string-formatting ready).

<s>The second line is crucial as this one will extract the values of the columns children, so if the code doesn't work out of the box - this is the place where you need to tweak it.</s>

Comment: `Columns[0].Children` - doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. I've replicated the OP's issue and adjusted the code so it complies and performs the requested dask.